# accept payment from credit card(Magento 1.9.4.2) php

Tags: php, magento, curl, magento-1.9

The Magento 1.9.4.2 has deprecated the Credit Card payment method, so I've decided to get the config.xml and system.xml from older version which is 1.8. It works btw.

My question is, once the customer input their credit card info, I want the bank(gateway for development) to verify it(I'm using a devsecure gateway service URL). My teacher told me to use cURL to do it but I am worried about how I'm going to do it. I'm new to Magento as well as PHP that's why I have no idea what to open to the directory. I am completely lost.

I don't know where to implement the cURL, in system.xml??cause it's where the Credit card functionalities are located at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has deprecated the Card Method in v1 for a reason. It was usually set to storing the card details which is not a secure way nowadays, as now everything is tokenised.

Every card provider has an API (not sure what devsecure is and how it is working, some docs would be useful).

What you should do, is create a custom module for the payment gateway (full fledged module) that actually handles the authorisation/charging aspect.

There are plenty of open source examples that would allow you to replicate some functionalty.

As it stands now the question doesn't provide enough details to help. Generally you need a custom module with a Payment Model for devsecure. the charging aspect would be handled using simple cURL requests within the module, or you could load a library like Guzzle to handle the HTTP requests.

Comment: I've been searching the internet for some open source examples but I can't find the right one that I need. Also, I have no idea which file to open to input those functionalities. BTW, do you know any sites that provide some open source examples that would be useful to me?

Comment: You are not going to find a "right" one. You would need to collect details from various to understand functionality.

Do you have any API docs for the gateway? what does the URL endpoint do?

This seems like a good example -> https://github.com/FourtekIT/Custom-payment-gateway-for-magento-1.9

And a useful example (with explanations) here -> https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-payment-method-module-in-magento-part-one--cms-23464

Comment: Yup, there's no such a right one. I have an API docs which is mainly about Credit Card payment. It shows all the details on how to capture the funds from the cardholder’s account. When I try to access the gateway, its just a blank page. Even if I cURL the URL, it shows nothing BUT I understand its purpose. Thanks for the the references